# Change status of Check Box in Access

Tags: checkbox

How can I change with only one click the status of the checkbox in the whole Access table? (There are about 30000 rows that's why I need to perform an automatic change)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `UPDATE` query, something like

```sql
UPDATE tableName SET checkboxField=1
```